# Is there a how to guide for testing livecode?

Tags: livecode

I have been trying for days to get a simple app any app made in livecode to display either on my tablet, smartphone or emulator.  It just doesn't work.  Here is what I have done:

1. I have installed my sdk and pointed livecode to it in preferences.
2. Picked 2.3 as my version
3. Check my google usb drivers and they are up to date.

I followed live code's step by step and no success. I am thinking that since I am running windows 7 not a Mac, maybe this cant be done.  It seems all the developers run Mac's?

I even tried to make a .apk, It made the file but " There was a problem parsing the package" once I got it on my Galaxy tab.  I made sure that I checked the box to allow programs to run on my tablet.  So I am still stuck.

Comment: Emulator seems too slow for testing. In my case, I prefer to test it directly on my device. So, just plug your android device (developer options enabled) and select your device as test target (Development -> test target). Be sure to select "Sign in for development only" for signing.

Answer (score 1):

To see if the SDK is working correctly you could try to use the Android SDK emulator first.
Open the Android SDK Manager and select the menu Tools->Manage AVDs.
There you can create a virtual Android device and run it. 
If the virtual device is running you can see the virtual device  under "Development->Test Target in Livecode. Select it and either select "Test" under "Development" or press the "Test" button. Does this work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Matthias. My device virtual device  is running, the app gets installed, but when I to launch the app it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

That error message means that the operating system on your device is preventing the app from being installed. The most likely reason for this is that you haven't changed the "Allow installation of apps from Unknown Sources" setting on your Galaxy Tab. There are other reasons and solutions for this error message - to see them visit Panagiotis's excellent blog post on the LiveCode website, your error message is in the fifth example
https://livecode.com/how-to-deploy-apps-to-android-devices/